# How to create an Email Account in Cpanel via PHP?

Tags: php, email, cpanel

How do I create email accounts with PHP using the xmlapi.php library from cPanel?

Note: I need to create more than 1000 email accounts and want to know if this is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean Message-IDs (the ones you use in e-mail headers)?

Comment: How is this up-voted already? I can't even begin to understand this question...

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by an "email id"?

Comment: @Matt Gibson: He means an email account. *... need to have a mail id from my domain (for eg : parrot@mysite.com )*

Comment: I need to create an email id as " alex@mysite.com " for the person alex while he registers in my website.

Comment: That's usually refered to as an email address (although more correctly its an ADDR-SPEC)

Comment: Should not have been closed.  This question is asking how to use the cPanel API to create an email account.  Heres the link to the API function:  http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/vief/ApiDocs/Api2/ApiEmail#Account%20functions

Comment: Yet *another* example on Stack of, "I don't understand the question so we must blindly vote-to-close." BS. >__>

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATED**

I have updated your question and based on that providing this answer.

**1.** I see bunch of API's for cPanel for managing the server. Though I don't find a direct API for creating a new email account, but found a script which would help you creating email account.

Please see this link:

> http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/cpanel-create-email-account.php
>
> http://forums.cpanel.net/f42/xmlapi-php-class-111897.html

Comment: correct, i do not think any host will allow you to do that.

Comment: I have a control panel access and able to create email ids form cpanel. 

But i need a option to create members who register in my site will need to have a mail id from my domain (for eg : parrot@mysite.com )

so is this possible to do ?

Thanks...

Comment: @Mohandass: See http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/WebHome

Answer (score 0):

You can *automate* the creation of email id's but creating a *http-client* that is logging into you cpanel-interface and then performing the needed *http-requests* to create the email-ids (email accounts).

Something similar [has been asked by Iain Clark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321310/applying-htaccess-folder-username-password-with-php) (Applying .htaccess folder username/password with PHP).

If you write such an automation in PHP you can then create Email-IDs from your PHP script.

Code for similar tasks can be found here and there in the web (e.g. [PHP Script To Log Into cPanel](http://www.thelinuxblog.com/php-script-to-log-into-cpanel/)), however you should carefully check if that is dealing with your passwords appropriate and that it actually works for your version/style/theme of cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion I eventually worked out that you're trying to create a username.

Automatic generation of usernames sucks. They do have to be unique though. Why not let your users pick their own names and reject ones that are already in use.